# Object scoping rules seem to change due to seemingly irrelevant library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ws

So, I'm familiar with the general gist of JavaScript's features regarding objects. They're refcounted and if they go to zero, they die. Additionally, `apple = banana` where both are objects doesn't copy `banana` to `apple` but makes `apple` a reference to `banana`.

That being said, some of my code has something like this:

```
// imagine ws require() and setup here...
var RateLimit = require("ws-rate-limit")('10s', 80);

SickWebsocketServer.on("connection", function(mysocket, req){
    // blahblahblah...
    RateLimit(mysocket); // See below...
    mysocket.on("limited", function(){console.log("someone was limited!"});
    mysocket.on("message", function(data){
         if(JSON.parse(msg).MyFlagToMessageASpecificWebsocketClient){ // obvs dont do this lol
             findme = MyArr.find(guy=>guy.Socket==mysocket);
    
             if(findme) console.log("TRIGGER PLS :)"); // GOAL
             else console.log("DON'T TRIGGER"); // SOMETHING WENT WRONG
         }
    });
    MyArr.push({MyName:"my SICK object", MyNumber:MyArr.length, Socket:mysocket})
}
```

The library used for rate limiting is called ws-rate-limit and I have pasted a shortened (non-code removed) version down below (since it's tiny). Imagine it to be in a package called ws-rate-limit (because it is :D).

```
const duration = require('css-duration')

module.exports = rateLimit

function rateLimit (rate, max) {
  const clients = []

  // Create an interval that resets message counts
  setInterval(() => {
    let i = clients.length
    while (i--) clients[i].messageCount = 0
  }, duration(rate))

  // Apply limiting to client:
  return function limit (client) {
    client.messageCount = 0
    client.on('newListener', function (name, listener) {
      if (name !== 'message' || listener._rated) return

      // Rate limiting wrapper over listener:
      function ratedListener (data, flags) {
        if (client.messageCount++ < max) listener(data, flags)
        else client.emit('limited', data, flags)
      }
      ratedListener._rated = true
      client.on('message', ratedListener)

      // Unset user's listener:
      process.nextTick(() => client.removeListener('message', listener))
    })

    // Push on clients array, and add handler to remove from array:
    clients.push(client)
    client.on('close', () => clients.splice(clients.indexOf(client), 1))
  }
}
```

My issue is that, when I do use the RateLimit function, the "DON'T TRIGGER" code triggers. If I literally remove that one single line (`RateLimit(mysocket)`) it goes into "TRIGGER PLS :)".

The above is obviously logically simplified from my actual application but I think you get the gist. Apologies for any misspellings that may lead to undefineds or stuff like that; I promise you my code works if not for the `RateLimit(mysocket)` line.

When I add console.logs into the find function to log both the guy.Socket object and the mysocket object, *with* the `RateLimit(mysocket)` line, the mysocket object's .toString() returns [object global] rather than [object Object]. I *know* that this is some complicated JavaScript object scoping problem, but I have no clue where to start in terms of investigating it.

Thank you! :)

Comment: what is `msg`? `req.message`? Also, may be its better to find by socket.id rather than comparing socket objects

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this code - I should have hashed the socket's id or something similar and used the JS object as a hashtable. However, that detracts from the fact that... well... it turns an [object Object] into an [object Global] - and I have no idea about the difference.

Comment: `global` is the global variables scope in node, just like `window` in browser. I am assuming the mySocket object is now in global scope(losing the context), because of whatever the `Ratelimiter` is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a random shot in the dark based on intuition.  My best guess is that your issue is with the `guy.Socket==mysocket` line.  Comparing objects that way will only check if they both point to the same heap memory location, even if it's two different stack variables.  In your example I can only assume that the `RateLimit(mysocket)` line is somehow creating a new heap location for that stack variable (creating a new object from it) and because of that your `==` comparison is then no longer equal (even if they have the exact same values) because they're pointing to different locations.

Try using: `JSON.stringify(guy.socket) === JSON.stringify(mysocket)`.